# PhpStorm showing "unvailable" breakpoint whereas execution is suspended

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm sometimes stuck while attempting to debug my code.
Debug Session is active, code execution is suspended :

[image: debug is on and smthg gets hit]

But I cannot see what really happens, as the breakpoint show "unavailable" ("no parking" symbol):

[image]

Does anybody know about this sign ?

I still haven't found any information about it on JetBrains sites... that's why I'm here :-)

(PhpStorm 2020.3, using docker containers (linux containers) with Docker Desktop/ Windows 10)

[EDIT] :
I just noticed that "break at first line in php script" seem to be functioning though:

[image]

But I have these weird breakpoints instead of red "normal" ones, and an highlighted line.

I tried restarting my docker containers, same issue. This produces seemingly randomly and gets solved after a while ... (reboot ?...)

[EDIT] *SOLVED*
The path mapping (local<->docker) for the root of my project was empty (how did it happen...) in my docker configuration in PhPStorm.
I'm not sure how this problem occured, but I'll be able to solve it next time if it's back.

Comment: 1) What's a "parking symbol"? Sadly I do not know what you mean here. 2) What kind of line/code that is? That symbol alone does not tell me much. The best guess right now -- Xdebug is unable to put a breakpoint there / cannot resolve the breakpoint. Xdebug log should show more info about that (as it normally logs that). 3) if it's not that -- will be good to see breakpoint details (bring popup with ALL breakpoint and bring details for that one).

Comment: @LazyOne thx
1 I meant what you could find with google  images by typing "no parking symbol"
2 any line
3 I've edited my description

Comment: Sadly that new screenshot with debugger window does not provide any new info for me. Now I got what you mean by "no parking" (I mean -- that it is the symbol itself). My best guess right now here -- the breakpoint was not resolved. I really cannot say anything more concrete with that little info about the project and stuff. There could be some easy nuance (bits of info that look normal to you but are wrong/missing to me)... but I simply not aware/cannot make it put from this info. Xdebug log / Xdebug config screenshots, better a small screencast on a simple test code is more than welcome here.

Comment: Thx again : I prefer not to share code in that case, but I can say that this is a problem that I randomly encounter. I sadly don't know how this solves "by itself". 99,99% of the time breakpoints are ok... Perhaps a false manipulation... I will keep this post updated if ever understand what the cause is...
I make a new edit (I'm using a docker containers)

Comment: Re: "no parking" icon. The icon itself means "Invalid breakpoint" as per IntelliJ Platform UI Guidelines: https://jetbrains.github.io/ui/resources/icons_list/. Enable and collect Xdebug log and look into details there (look for breakpoints for that file & line number and what Xdebug says about them).

Comment: @LazyOne thank you I've edited again : SOLVED :-)

Comment: So it was missing path mappings. Post your solution as a proper answer (you can mark it as accepted later) -- this will help a lot other users in a similar situation.

Comment: Well, you're right that is done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to disable "break at first line in php scripts" you may get the message :

[image: PhPStorm Message about path mappings]

> 17:38 Debug session was finished without being paused             It may be
> caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and
> remote projects.          To figure out the problem check path mappings
> configuration for 'docker-server' server at PHP|Servers or enable
> Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).            Do not
> show again

In my case, the path mapping for the root of my project was incomplete "Absolute path on the server" was emtpy. I don't know how it happened but you could check :

In PHP | Servers

[image: PHP|Servers]